# Run Angular and legacy Knockout app at the same time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, knockout.js

I have the pleasure / misfortune to begin rewriting a legacy Knockout application with Angular. It has to happen in stages because its a large app. Right now I'm rebuilding everything under the `/account` route. I also have to do this on an ASP.NET MVC solution.

I've managed to develop, build, and run the application well enough by delivering the static assets for any account route. However, in an attempt to prevent having to reload the application every time someone navigates between their account and the rest of the app, I'd like to find a way to spin up the angular app at the same time as the knockout app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have a silly idea, but it will require extra development from you.

Maybe you can run everything inside your Angular app?

1. Your Angular app should take care of all routing.
2. Knockout pages could run inside of a [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) and interact with Angular by [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Basic concept:

1. Angular app opened
2. User try to go to Knockout page
3. Angular show loading state
4. Angular start to load [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) with a knockout page (iframe is hidden)
5. iframe notify Angular via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) that it is ready (need to change routing or initialization logic of your knockout app)
6. Angular stops loading and show iframe
7. User interacts with knockout page
8. If user clicks on some element that require redirect - knockout should notify Angular via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) about it.

*I was able to describe only basic idea without knowing details about your app.*